# Translation For Dynamic Data Using Rails I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

My very first question on stack overflow cheers for that..I just want to know is there a way to convert the data coming from database to Spanish language.As I am able to translate the static data using es.yml but i am looking for a way to convert the dynamic data.
Thanks In Advance..

Comment: https://github.com/globalize/globalize, there's a gem for that.

Comment: Yes, this is possible.  Please add some examples of what you want to do.

Comment: @MaxWilliams : Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I have a model Notification that has a column called body.The value stored in this column is in English language but i need to convert this body to Spanish.Is there a way out to do so.Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write each translation into your en.yml

Alternatively, you can use google translate plugin